# Were the בגדי לבן‎ 30 ‎מנה in weight or value?

Tags: clothing, yom-kippur, kohen-priest, mishna, masechet-yoma

I'm studying משניות מסכת יומא and have come across this passage (in chapter 3 mishna 7, found in [the *Bavli*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilna_Shas) on page 34:2):

> בשחר היה לובש פלוסין של שנים עשר מנה ובין הערבים הנדוין של שמונה מאות זוז דברי רבי מאיר וחכמים אומרים בשחר היה לובש של שמונה עשר מנה ובין הערבים של שנים עשר מנה הכל שלשים מנה אלו משל צבור ואם רצה להוסיף מוסיף משלו
>
> In the morning [of *Yom Kipur*, the *kohen gadol*] would wear Egyptian [clothes] of twelve *mane* [=1200 *zuz*], and in the afternoon Indian of 800 *zuz*: the words of Rabbi *Meir*. The sages said: in the morning, he would wear [clothes] of eighteen *mane* and in the afternoon of twelve *mane*, a total of thirty *mane*. These are from the assets of the community; if he wanted to add, he could add from his own.

*Mane* and *zuz* were units of currency and of weight. Does this passage refer to the clothes' value (or cost) or to their weight?

(I don't see that any of the commentaries in [a standard version of משניות](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37942&pgnum=25) state clearly one way or the other.)

Comment: 18 maneh is almost 20 pounds. That's pretty heavy for just cloth.

Comment: @DoubleAA They were four garments including an exceedingly long belt. It is pretty heavy, I agree, but far from inconceivably so.

Comment: While looking for a possible answer, I found http://www.templeinstitute.org/beged/priestly_garments.htm which has all sorts of information on the priestly garments EXCEPT cloth weight/value requirements. Nice read, though...

Comment: @msh210 where does it say that Zuz is a unit of weight?

Comment: @PloniAlmoni … or of money? Yeah, I should cite a source for those claims. I can't at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

[Rav Pinchas Kehati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinchas_Kehati) explains the Mishna is speaking in terms of **monetary value** of the clothes which the Kohen Gadol wore.

*Source from [Torah Community Connections](https://web.archive.org/web/20081227203147/http://www.moreshet.net/oldsite/index.htm) for full text of the Mishna explained click [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20090105201918/http://www.moreshet.net//oldsite/mishna/18-6-00/tuesday.htm)*

> ***In the morning** - for the morning service, **he** - the High Priest, **put on Pelusin** - white garments made of fine, excellent linen which came from the city of Pelusium in Egypt; according to one opinion, Pelusium is identical with Ramses: Targum Yerushalmi translates "Ramses" as "Pelusin," **of** - worth - **twelve maneh** - one maneh = 100 dinars; **and for the afternoon service, Hindvin** - white linen garments from India (see Tosefot Yom Tov), **of eight hundred zuz** - eight maneh;*
>
> ***So says Rabbi Meir** - who holds that the total amount of money expended from Temple funds on the garments of the High Priest is twenty maneh. **But the Sages say, in the morning he put on of eighteen maneh, and in the afternoon of twelve maneh, in all thirty maneh**...*

Hope this can be helpful.